# Synchronous HTTPS POST Request iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, ssl, https

For Android, I've been able to send POST requests in the following way:

```
HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://somewebsite.com");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
http.execute(request);
```

However, on iOS I get the following error:

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
```

What is the best way to perform a synchronous POST request using https on iOS?

Comment: You need to provide your iOS code. The Android code is not throwing an iOS domain error :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this function:

```
-(NSData *)post:(NSString *)postString url:(NSString*)urlString{

    //Response data object
    NSData *returnData = [[NSData alloc]init];

    //Build the Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Send the Request
    returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

    //Get the Result of Request
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    bool debug = YES;

    if (debug && response) {
        NSLog(@"Response >>>> %@",response);
    }


    return returnData;
}
```

And here is how you use it:

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param=%@",param];
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.yourapi.com";

NSData *returnData =  [self post:postString url:urlString];
```

Edit:

I found the error code in the source code:

`errSSLHostNameMismatch     = -9843,    /* peer host name mismatch */`

The problem should be address on your server.

And here is from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000155-CH5g-BCICDCBA):

> **errSSLHostNameMismatch  -9843**  The host name you connected with does
>   not match any of the host names allowed by the certificate. This is
>   commonly caused by an incorrect value for the kCFStreamSSLPeerName
>   property within the dictionary associated with the stream’s
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings key. Available in OS X v10.4 and later.

hope this help

Comment: This gets me the error posted in the question, namely "NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)".

Comment: This is for production code. The answer at the link states: "Do not use this code for production but only while developing your app in cases where the certificate is not yet approved/submitted/installed. Typical would be the use of a development server that does not have a trusted certificate installed. The use of this code will get your App rejected from distribution via iTunes as it uses a private API method."

Comment: Please see my edit, you have to fix it on your server