# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843) fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, parsing, option-type

I know that the http load fails because of ATS, but I ve already implemented the code which should disable ATS in my INFO.plist. Here it is:

```
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have no idea why it fails. I have tried out different codes which should disable ATS. And I have unwrapped every optional so why does it found nil?

```
    import UIKit

protocol XMLParserDelegate {
    func XMLParserError(parser: XMLParser, error: String)
}

class XMLParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    let url: NSURL
    var delegate: XMLParserDelegate?

    var objects = [Dictionary<String,String>]()
    var object = Dictionary<String,String>()

    var inItem = false
    var current = String()

    var handler: (() -> Void)?

    init(url: NSURL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func deleteObjects() {
        objects.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        object.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        inItem = false
        handler = nil
    }

    func parse(handler: () -> Void) {
        self.handler = handler

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            // Anderer Thread

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            let xmlCode = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.url)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: xmlCode!)
            parser.delegate = self
            if !parser.parse() {
                self.delegate?.XMLParserError(self, error: "Parsen fehlgeschlagen")
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        delegate?.XMLParserError(self, error: parseError.localizedDescription)
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            object.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            inItem = true
        }
        current = elementName
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if !inItem {
            return
        }
        if let temp = object[current] {
            var tempString = temp
            tempString += string
            object[current] = tempString
        }
        else {
            object[current] = string
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "item" {
            inItem = false
            objects.append(object)
        }
    }

    func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // MAIN QUEUE
            if self.handler != nil {
                self.handler!()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help you or not, but I was getting error `-9802` with a similar setup to what you have . I checked the website I was loading and noticed that they were loading their CSS/Javascript files from a different domain. Adding the additional domain to my plist resolved my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this link is useful: [Synchronous HTTPS POST Request iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335168/synchronous-https-post-request-ios)
It's because of the server. I also encountered this problem when I post to a url, while my device connecting to a wifi that needs to be logined.