# How to send parameters with base64 image string using POST method in iOS?

Tags: ios, post, parameters, base64

I have parameters FirstName,LastName,Email & image ,Which need to send in the form of base64.I need appropriate code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 is used to convert binary data into text.

In your situation only Image needs to be encoded in that format, the rest should be text.

[Convert UIImage to Base64 string in Objective-C and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-uiimage-to-base64-string-in-objective-c-and-swift)

Comment: I have base 64 string but I need how to post parameters along with image strings

Comment: @RakeshBiswal its just a string you post it like any other post param

Comment: @RakeshBiswal you using objective c or swift

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335168/synchronous-https-post-request-ios/25335314#25335314

Comment: Follow my answer in the link above